# Resize a single image on a canvas with multiple images

Tags: reactjs, canvas

Using react, I have a canvas on which I have a background image. Also I add a couple of other images (logo's mainly). Now I want to be able to resize a single image (one of the logo's), but when I do that the background is gone, I know that this is because of a piece of code I use:

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
```

How can I resize a logo image, while the background image remains as it is.

Comment: A canvas is just one image. The only way to edit a single part of it is by redrawing ALL parts of the canvas.